# How to Import/export SQL Server tables via XML files

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am receiving data files in XML format from a public agency. The structure of the files and the notations within make me think that what I am seeing is a bulk table dump from SQL Server. Each XML file starts with a schema definition.  This is followed by multiple elements, each element looking like it contains one table row of data.  The structure of the files makes me think that they were created by some facility within SQL Server itself.

I have looked at the SQL Server docs and online articles, but I cannot find information on how this would be accomplished.  I am thinking that if there is a built in facility to export the data in this format, there must be a built in facility to import the data back into SQL Server.

A snippet of one XML file showing the opening schema section and a couple of data elements can be found here;
[sample data XML file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdifu0m0udhntzh/sample.xml?dl=0)

Am I correct in thinking that these files are SQL Server dumps?  If so, who are these exported and then imported?

Comment: It is much simpler to import xml using a language like c# and then saving to database than to attempt to do it with the SQL script language.

Comment: Don't link to off site resources for your data; put it in the text of your question.

Comment: Larnu -- I tried to put the XML into the question section, but the page mangled it.  Is there a formatting directive that will preserve the XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml functionality of SQL Server. Something like this.

**Import**

```
declare @x xml = N'--your xml here'

; with xmlnamespaces('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1' as p)--required as xml has xmlns attribute
--insert mytable
select t.v.value('p:pool_idn[1]','int') pool_idn, --note p: prefix
t.v.value('p:eff_dte[1]','datetime') eff_dte,
t.v.value('p:pool_nam[1]','varchar(50)') pool_nam
--and so on
from @x.nodes('root/p:pool') t(v)
```

**Export**

```
select * from mytable
for xml auto, elements, root, xmlschema('urn:my:schema')
```